# Create a resolved A+ Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

This is a pretty esoteric question.

What is a simple way of writing a function which accepts a single value and returns a compliant [Promises/A+](http://promisesaplus.com/) which is immediately resolved with the provided value. I want to do this without using an existing library.

I think I've figured it out, but the spec is very specific and I feel like I might have missed something. I'm also curious to know if there is a better way to do it.

Essentially, does the following meet the A+/Promises specification for creating a resolved promise.

```
var resolvedPromise = (function() {
  function makePromise(isRejected, value) {
    var promise1;

    promise1 = {
      then: function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        var callback, promise2;

        promise2 = promise1;

        callback = isRejected ? onRejected : onFulfilled;

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
          try {
            promise2 = callback(value);
          }
          catch (ex) {
            promise2 = makePromise(true, ex);
          }
        }

        if (promise2 == null || typeof promise2.then !== 'function') {
          promise2 = makePromise(false, promise2);
        }

        return promise2;
      }
    }

    return promise1;
  }

  return makePromise.bind(null, false);
})();
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Is this just for learning? (Also no, your implementation is not A+ complaint)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm trying to add some basic interoperability with A+/Promises in a library that I'm working on and I don't want to have to pull in a big promise library like Q or When just so that I can wrap some values in resolved promises.

Comment: So use a lightweight promise library, some are only 1-2 KB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a simple way of writing a function which accepts a single value and returns a compliant Promises/A+ which is immediately resolved with the provided value. I want to do this without using an existing library.

There is none. Basically, creating a Promises/A+ compliant promise without using an existing library means that you have to write your own compatible library; and that's a non-trivial task.

> the spec is very specific and I feel like I might have missed something.

The Promises/A+ spec is only about how the `.then` method of a Promise should work, and how libraries should deal with objects that have `then` methods but are not instances of the own Promise type.

The spec does not say anything about how or by what methods a Promise object is created, nor how it is getting resolved.

> I think I've figured it out

No, your `then` method violates a few points of the spec; most specifically #2.2.4:

> *`onFulfilled` or `onRejected` must not be called until the execution
>   context stack contains only platform code.*
>
> *Here “platform code” means engine, environment, and promise
>   implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that
>   `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` **execute asynchronously**, after the event
>   loop turn in which `then` is called, and with a fresh stack. This can be
>   implemented with either a “macro-task” mechanism such as `setTimeout` or
>   `setImmediate`, or with a “micro-task” mechanism such as
>   `MutationObserver` or `process.nextTick`. Since the promise implementation
>   is considered platform code, it may itself contain a task-scheduling
>   queue or “trampoline” in which the handlers are called*

Also, apart from the major complifications that arise from executing them async (even if the promise is already resolved) and still returning a promise for the result immediately, your current code doesn't follow the *Promise Resolution* details and just returns all objects with `then` methods right away, even if they are no conformant promises.

> I'm also curious to know if there is a better way to do it.

Use an existing library :-)

Comment: Damn. Thanks for your feedback - that asynchronous point is tricky but I still think it should be possible without much extra code. I'm trying to add some basic interoperability with A+/Promises in a library that I'm working on and I don't want to have to pull in a big promise library like Q or When just so that I can wrap some values in resolved promises.

Comment: @RemyD'Agostino accept a promise constructor from the library being interop'd with and call it. If you don't want to have the promise library in your code get the functionality in DI

Comment: Uh, executing the callbacks async and still returning a proper result promise will need a lot more code. You might want to check some of the smaller [implementations](http://promisesaplus.com/implementations) for ideas. For basic interoperability, you don't need to return a full-fledged promise, but only a thenable like you already do. Then let your user just wrap that in an actual promise of his chosen library.